# How to add a special character in an avro name

Tags: avro

I want to create an avro schema which one of the record would have a special character in it's name.

```
[{
"name": "Example",
"type": "record",
"namespace": "com.example",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "@example",
    "type": "string"
  }
]}]
```

The error returned :

```
Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.9.2:schema failed: Illegal initial character: @example
```

So far I tried utilizing the aliases field, but it has not been conclusive.

Comment: Maybe you can explain your use case here?

Comment: I am trying to create a Spring Boot REST API that would convert a received JSON body to an AVRO Object in order to produce a message to a Kafka Topic. I am using MapStruct as my mapper and so far so good, but I want to avoid finding specific name field that needs an @ in the name and add it.

Answer (score 2):

The specification states that names can only have A through Z characters, numbers 0 through 9, and underscore. Anything else is not allowed which is why you are getting that error.

Reference: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names

Comment: More precisely, it follows the same rules as Java identifier names